Is a 4mm banana jack suitable to handle PWM in the range of 10kHz to 300kHz?
Is a 4mm banana jack a suitable connector type for handling PWM in the 10kHz to 300kHz range?
If not, what would be a suitable connector type?

You didn't mention voltage and current requirements. How are you preventing EMI? Hit the [edit] link ...

Yes, absent any other requirements, a banana jack is suitable for a PWM signal in the 10 kHz to 300 kHz range.

No.
A banana jack (as in a single one) would be a terrible choice, because with an uncertain signal return path, the edges can be massively distorted.
Bananas can work, but you have to use two in parallel, for the signal and its return line.
A better choice for a pluggable interdevice interconnect would be BNC.
